# Switching Views with Gluon Charm

Tags: javafx, javafxports, gluon

I'm trying to build an application with multiple views. I've successfully added two views but when I try switching to a third view I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at com.airhacks.afterburner.views.FXMLView.loadSynchronously(FXMLView.java:91)
at com.airhacks.afterburner.views.FXMLView.initializeFXMLLoader(FXMLView.java:100)
at com.airhacks.afterburner.views.FXMLView.getPresenter(FXMLView.java:179)
at com.testapp.gpa.TestApp.lambda$init$2(TestApp.java:46)
at com.testapp.gpa.TestApp.access$lambda$2(TestApp.java)
at com.testapp.gpa.TestApp$$Lambda$5.get(Unknown Source)
at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.d.a.a(SourceFile:32)
at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.switchView(SourceFile:344)
at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.switchView(SourceFile:312)
```

Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

I can switch from the homeview to the SemesterView. But I can't switch to the CourseView. The views are just empty classes that extend the FXMLView class. I'm following the project structure of the Comments sampe app.
Here's the first line of the course.fxml file

```
<View maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.testapp.views.courses.CoursePresenter">
```

which points to the controller class.

Comment: `Location is not set` means the fxml file is not found when you try to load it. Please provide more details of how you add it to the project (project structure, name of files, ...)

Comment: I edited the question. Also, could you explain the role of the project structure? I just followed the structure of the Comments sample app and I don't know how the FXML, the Presenter and empty View classes interact.

Comment: Another important tip: fxml file must be all lowercase. It may work on Windows but will fail on a case sensitive OS like linux or android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have followed the Comments sample, there is a detailed [post](http://gluonhq.com/comments-app-getting-started-with-gluon-charm/) about it, explaining how the Gluon plugin generates the project, and where you have to add your code and resources.

Also it explains how to use the [Afterburner](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com) framework.

Since it's based on convention over configuration, for a view like `home` you have to define:

- In src/main/java directory: 
  `com.gluonhq.demo.comments.views.home` package and two classes: `HomeView` and `HomePresenter`.
- In the src/main/resources directory:
  `com.gluonhq.demo.comments.views.home` package and two files:  `home.fxml` and `home.css`.

In your project, you have: `home`, `semester` and `course`. Notice you have defined `CourseView` and `CoursePresenter`, so this is the reason the framework fails with the `Location is not set` exception: it is expecting `course.fxml`, but you have added `courses.fxml` instead. So either rename the classes to `CoursesView` and `CoursesPresenter`, or the fxml file to `course.fxml`.